# Swiper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined or TypeError: classNames is undefined

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I use [Swiper](https://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/) v4.5 for my project. When I open Chrome developer mode to watch my project, there is an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`. I also tried Swiper v4.2, and the same result. How should I fix this problem?

The whole project uses the following js:

```
- modernizr.min.js
- jquery.min.js
- bootstrap.min.js
- swiper.min.js
```

The error part of Swiper:

```
suffixes.forEach(function (suffix) {
      classNames.push(params.containerModifierClass + suffix);
});
```

Comment: Apparently, classNames is undefined.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Introduction**

Newer Swiper versions are completely broken for use in browsers it seems. Browsers seem to have incompatible JS. It seems you need to use some older version of Swiper.

As of Swiper 5.3.6, `swiper5_3_6/package/src/components/core/classes/addClasses.js` has the following:

```
export default function () {
  const swiper = this;
  const {
    classNames, params, rtl, $el,
  } = swiper;
```

[a lot of lines skipped]

```
  suffixes.forEach((suffix) => {
    classNames.push(params.containerModifierClass + suffix);
  });
```

**Answer**

A known good Swiper for browsers is version 3.3.1 which we use in production for a small project. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

When calling `new Swiper('.your-classname-here')`, make sure that your target exists